# For values in list above a number set boolean (true, false) in R

Tags: r

Suppose, I have a list

```
a <- c(3, 5, 2, 7, 9)
```

and I want to do a vector operation, something like:

`a_greater_than_five <- a[a>5]`

but I want results something like below:

```
a_greater_than_five <- c(false, false, false, true, true).
```

Something similar to numpy in python: [Check if all values in list are greater than a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20229822/2783516)

Comment: a>5 does not give what you want?

Comment: `a <- c(3, 5, 2, 7, 9)` it is not a list.

Comment: Using `[]` means you are subsetting your data. so doing `a[a>5]` will store values which are greater than `5` i.e. `7` and `9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>  a <- c(3, 5, 2, 7, 9)
> Result <- a>5
> Result
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

If

```
 a <- c(3, 5, 2, 7, 9)
```

then simply

```
a > 5   
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```